# How to access global var when local has been unset in Bash

Tags: bash

```
vv=1
cc() { local vv=2; echo $vv; unset vv; echo "${vv}3"; }
cc
echo $vv
```

Gives:

```
2
3
1
```

I was expecting:

```
2
13
1
```

How can I access the global variable once a variable with the same name has been set local in a function?

Comment: `vv="1"; cc() { global="$vv"; local vv="2"; echo "$vv"; unset vv; vv="$global"; echo "${vv}3"; }; cc; echo "$vv"`?

Comment: Depending on what you need to do with the local value, you can use an explicit subshell instead of the (nonstandard) `local` command to override the value of `vv` temporarily: `cc () { (vv=2; echo $vv); echo ${vv}3; }`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can. If it's an exported environment variable you can find it by reading the environment, but as far as a global variable masked by a local one, AFAIK you're out of luck. Check the contents of, and copy as necessary, before declaring your local variable.